# In Django, Problem with {{ block.super }}, How do I avoid duplicating a `block` in multiple template files?

Tags: django, include, django-templates

For 2 child template files inheriting a block, the `{{ block.super }}` does not resolve

Python 2.5.2, Django 1.0, Windows XP SP3

Sample skeleton code for files involved:

1. `base.html`
2. `item_base.html`
3. `show_info_for_all_items.html`
4. `show_info_for_single_item.html`

FILE : `base.html`

```
{% block content %}
{% endblock %}
```

FILE : `item_base.html`

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block item_info %}   
    Item : {{ item.name }}<br/>
    Price : {{ item.price }}<br/>   
{% endblock %}
```

FILE : `show_info_for_all_items.html`

```
{% extends "item_base.html" %}
{% block content %}
    <h1>info on all items</h1>
    <hr/>
    {% for item in items %}
        {% block item_info %}
            {{ block.super }}
        {% endblock %}
        <hr/>
    {% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```

FILE : `show_info_for_single_item.html`

```
{% extends "item_base.html" %}
{% block content %}
    <h1>info on single item</h1>    
    {% block item_info %}
        {{ block.super }}
    {% endblock %}  
{% endblock %}
```

`show_info_for_all_items.html` shows a list of items along with each item's info.

`show_info_for_single_item.html` shows a single item with the item's info.

`show_info_for_all_items.html` and `show_info_for_single_item.html` share same code for showing item info, so I moved it to `item_base.html` into `block item_info`

but the `{{ block.super }}` in `show_info_for_all_items.html` and `show_info_for_single_item.html` does not work. `{{ block.super }}` resolves as blank.

If I move the code back from `block item_info` in `item_base.html` into `show_info_for_all_items.html` and `show_info_for_single_item.html`  it works but then I have to duplicate same `block item_info` code in 2 files.

If the block.super issue can not be solved, does Django offer something like INCLUDE => `{% INCLUDE "item_base.html" %}` so blocks from a template file can be included ( instead of `extends` )

How do I avoid duplicating `block item_info` in both html files?

Comment: Had you googled on django+include you could have asked & answered this in a fraction of the time it took to type it in.

Comment: Embrace the non-Googlers : http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5280/embrace-the-non-googlers and How should we deal with Google questions? : http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8724/how-should-we-deal-with-google-questions

Comment: No, I will *not* embrace Help Vampires, and I do not agree with those who encourage them here. SO cannot and, IMNSHO, *should not try to* replace the high quality docs of a project like Django. Thinking that SO can and should is arrogance, plain and simple.

Comment: @PeterRowell - I agree the Help Vampires (good term) should be swatted on the nose, but I like the OP googled around this question for sometime before realizing `include` was the keyword that would have got me the result.  Its actually not listed in the "extending a template" docs [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/overriding-templates/#extending-an-overridden-template)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Does Django offer something like
>   INCLUDE (...)

Yes!, just take a look at the documentation: [include](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#include)

Put the common code block in *foo.html*, and then, in each template:

```
{% include 'foo.html' %}
```

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the `include` tag mentioned by DZPM, you might want to consider writing a [custom inclusion tag](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/#inclusion-tags).

The main advantage in this case is that the calling template doesn't have to use the same variable names as the included template.  You could show an item that is accessed from somewhere other than a variable named 'item':

```
{% show_item user.favorite_item %}
```